# Rsyslog duplicate logs (rsyslog.conf and rsyslog.d/something.conf)

Tags: php, rsyslog

I've created a custom log (PHP sends log entries to **rsyslog**) using local0. It uses a new custom file (`/var/log/sea.log`). The problem is that logs are being sent to `/var/log/sea.log`,  `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog`. How do I prevent that from happening? I need to send logs only to `/var/log/sea.log`.

`/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#           For more information see
#           /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


###############
#### RULES ####
###############

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*             /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*            -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*               -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
user.*              -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info           -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn           -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err            /var/log/mail.err

#
# Logging for INN news system.
#
news.crit           /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err            /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice         -/var/log/news/news.notice

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
*.=debug;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    news.none;mail.none -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    cron,daemon.none;\
    mail,news.none      -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg             :omusrmsg:*

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#   news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#   *.=debug;*.=info;\
#   *.=notice;*.=warn   /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
# 
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
    news.err;\
    *.=debug;*.=info;\
    *.=notice;*.=warn   |/dev/xconsole
```

`/etc/rsyslog.d/sea.conf`:

```
local0.info                     /var/log/sea.log
local0.none                     /var/log/messages
local0.none                     /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use the 'final' option after your statements. Much easier.

```
local.0 /var/log/sea.log
&~
```

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something. OP, this is the better answer.

Comment: Thanks!!
Are these the same?
local0.*                        /var/log/sea.log
--OR--
local.0                         /var/log/sea.log

Comment: @brgsousa - yes. You can actually use the wildcard so it's literally local0.* if you want as well. I was writing it up from my phone otherwise I would have included the extra details. :)

Comment: Where is this documented? Searching for `&~` is hard.

Comment: @MartinSchröder your best bet is going through the manual.

Comment: The & allows you to add more actions for a given selector on subsequent lines.  The ~ indicates a "discard" action, which stops any further processing of that message.  Combining them makes the preceding line the final action for that message.  http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/actions.html

Answer (score 2):

Look at this line; `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`. It shows up *above* all of the standard rules. You need to add **local0.none** to the `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog` rules in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have debugged on the server cannot find anything and *still* getting duplicates, it is possible the *client* might be double posting entries. That was the case for me.